# Laravel : Select and GroupBy SQL Query Error. Multiple Selects with groupBy? Is it Possible?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sqlite, laravel-5.5

I have an 2 tables Ratings and Attributes , i pass the month and get all record of both users and count this , i have already count this record , and divided into groups by user_id , But in my attribute table i have a user name , and join this table to get attribute name , My query is that

```
$months = \Request::get('month');

$records = DB::table("ratings")

    ->select(DB::raw("SUM(ratings.attribute_score) as score"))
    ->whereRaw('MONTH(ratings.created_at) = '.$months)
    ->join('users','ratings.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->groupBy('ratings.user_id')
    ->get();

dd($records);
```

And get json like that
 [image: result of this query]

But i want to get name of the specific user with score but here multiple selects  not working in this query how to use multiple select to get attributes table records? if i am using this query. Thanks Developers in advance

```
->select(DB::raw("SUM(ratings.attribute_score) as score , ratings.user_id , attributes.attributes_name"))
```

Using this the select not working here it always return the score Jason like show in the Sceenshot. How can i do to selects multiples using groupBy??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE THIS TO GET USERNAME WITH SCORE COUNTS. Try This

```
$months = \Request::get('month');

$records = DB::table("ratings")
    ->select(DB::raw('SUM(ratings.attribute_score) as score, users.name as 
      user_name'))
    ->whereRaw('MONTH(ratings.created_at) = '.$months)
    ->join('users','ratings.user_id','=','users.id')
    ->groupBy('users.name')
    ->get();   
return view('attribute.show' , compact('records'));
```